# Roku development: Problem of SceneGraph Development Extensions

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I tried to use ComponentController to navigate from Main Scene to ViewA, then I found two problem

1. The button in ViewA does not respond to remote events. (button.setFocus(true))
2. The font:LargeBoldSystemFont/font:MediumBoldSystemFont does not work normally

I am new to Roku development. Any hint is appreciated.

**Update:**

I figured out the solution for 1
I was not supposed to setFocus in init() function.
I have to add
`m.top.observeField("focusedChild","onChildFocused")` to init()

Then setFocus in onChildFocused

```
sub onChildFocused()
    print "child focused"
    if m.top.isInFocusChain() and not m.button.hasFocus() then
      m.button.setFocus(true)
    end if 
end sub
```

I still don't know why the fonts don't work normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your question what issue you are facing with fonts. If your question is regarding button text font, check whether you are setting fonts for "*textFont*" and "*focusedTextFont*" both for the button.